# how to avoid linux command messages in linux

Tags: linux, shell, command

How can I avoid messages that are shown on shell after I enter a command in ubuntu?

For example dd command in linux outputs something like " n bytes copied ...." and I want to avoid these outputs.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect output with the '>' operator:

```
dd ... 1>/dev/null
```

1 is the standard output (stdout), 2 the standard error (stderr).

See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html for a complete explanation of IO redirection.